# One to One and One to Many Optional Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I have a model like this :

```cs
public class PortStackingDetails
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? StackingExtendDetailsId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("StackingExtendDetailsId")]
    public virtual StackingExtendDetails StackingExtendDetails { get; set; }
}

public class StackingExtendDetails
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int PortStackingDetailsId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PortStackingDetailsId")]
    public virtual PortStackingDetails PortStackingDetails { get; set; }
}
```

- `StackingExtendDetails` must have one `PortStackingDetails` (one-to-one)
- `PortStackingDetails` optionally can have one `StackingExtendDetails` (one-to-one)
- `PortStackingDetails` can be related to many `StackingExtendDetails` because `PortStackingDetails` can be extended (created) a few times using `StackingExtendDetails`

The process is actually simple. When `PortStackingDetails` created, it has no `StackingExtendDetailsId`. Later when `StackingExtendDetails` created, it will update `StackingExtendDetailsId`  in `PortStackingDetails`. So basically `StackingExtendDetailsId` used to track the latest `StackingExtendDetails` using `PortStackingDetails`.

I got error when using this in Entity Framework and ASP.NET MVC 5.

> Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the
> types 'ERP.Models.StackingExtendDetails' and
> 'ERP.Models.PortStackingDetails'. The principal end of this
> association must be explicitly configured using either the
> relationship fluent API or data annotations.

Is it possible make this relationship in data annotation only? I tried some Fluent API from chatGPT, but none of it works.

If in SQL Server script, I want to have relationship like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PortStackingDetails]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [StackingExtendDetailsId] [int] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.PortStackingDetails] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StackingExtendDetails]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PortStackingDetailsId] [int] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.StackingExtendDetails] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
) 
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PortStackingDetails] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.PortStackingDetails_dbo.StackingExtendDetails_StackingExtendDetailsId] 
        FOREIGN KEY([StackingExtendDetailsId])
        REFERENCES [dbo].[StackingExtendDetails] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PortStackingDetails] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.PortStackingDetails_dbo.StackingExtendDetails_StackingExtendDetailsId]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[StackingExtendDetails] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.StackingExtendDetails_dbo.PortStackingDetails_PortStackingDetailsId] 
        FOREIGN KEY([PortStackingDetailsId])
        REFERENCES [dbo].[PortStackingDetails] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[StackingExtendDetails] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.StackingExtendDetails_dbo.PortStackingDetails_PortStackingDetailsId]
GO
```

Comment: Do you use EF Core or the old EF?

Comment: @vernou EF 6.4.4 for MVC5

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to do a `one-to-one` and a `one-to-many` between the same tables.

You need to pick one or the other.

However, if you want to extend `PortStackingDetails` with `StackingExtendDetails`, then it's possible with Data annotations.

```
public class PortStackingDetails
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual StackingExtendDetails StackingExtendDetails { get; set; }
}

public class StackingExtendDetails
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int PortStackingDetailsId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PortStackingDetailsId")]
    public virtual PortStackingDetails PortStackingDetails { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

Comment: hmm I need to navigate latest updated `StackingExtendDetails` from `PortStackingDetails` in my case. But sometime it is not latest updated by time or Id, it has no particular order, thats why I need it to be updated into `PortStackingDetails` too

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any solution for data annotation only. But I am be able to create it using Fluent API :

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<PortStackingDetails>()
            .HasKey(p => p.Id)
            .HasOptional(p => p.StackingExtendDetails)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.StackingExtendDetailsId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<StackingExtendDetails>()
            .HasKey(s => s.Id)
            .HasRequired(s => s.PortStackingDetails)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(s => s.PortStackingDetailsId);
```